# PyTorch-lightning models running out of Memory after 1st epoch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I saw a Kaggle kernel on PyTorch and run it with the same img_size, batch_size, etc. and created another PyTorch-lightning kernel with exact same values but my lightning model runs out of memory after about 1.5 epochs (each epoch contains 8750 steps) on the first fold whereas the native PyTorch model runs for whole 5 folds. Is there any way to improve the code or release memory? I could have tried to delete the models or do some garbage collection but if it doesn't complete even the first fold I can't delete the models and things.

```
def run_fold(fold):
    
    df_train = train[train['fold'] != fold]
    df_valid = train[train['fold'] == fold]
    
    train_dataset = G2NetDataset(df_train, get_train_aug())
    valid_dataset = G2NetDataset(df_valid, get_test_aug())
    
    train_dl = DataLoader(train_dataset,
                          batch_size = config.batch_size,
                          num_workers = config.num_workers,
                          shuffle = True,
                          drop_last = True,
                          pin_memory = True)
    
    valid_dl = DataLoader(valid_dataset,
                         batch_size = config.batch_size,
                         num_workers = config.num_workers,
                         shuffle = False,
                         drop_last = False,
                         pin_memory = True)
    
    
    model = Classifier()
    logger = pl.loggers.WandbLogger(project='G2Net', name=f'fold: {fold}')
    
    trainer = pl.Trainer(gpus = 1, 
                         max_epochs = config.epochs,
                         fast_dev_run = config.debug,
                         logger = logger,
                         log_every_n_steps=10)
    
    trainer.fit(model, train_dl, valid_dl)
    result = trainer.test(test_dataloaders = valid_dl)
    wandb.run.finish() 
    return result

def main():   
    if config.train:
        results = []
        for fold in range(config.n_fold):
            result = run_fold(fold)
            results.append(result)      
    return results

results = main()
```

Comment: Maybe one thing to try is to use .detach()  to any tensor you don't need in a current loop most probably when you calculate metrics. This way you are not storing tensors and their entire graph for no reason. Have you tried this?

Comment: But I am using Pytorch-Lightning and hence there is no way to detach at any given point as lightning manages all the stuff in the background.

Comment: Hi, can you attach a snippet of your train function. It will be easier to debug then.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say much without looking at your model class, but couple possible issues that I encountered were metric and loss evaluation for logging.
For example, stuff like

```
pl.metrics.Accuracy(compute_on_step=False)
```

requires and explicit call of .compute()

```
def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    loss = sum([out['loss'] for out in outputs])/len(outputs)
    self.log_dict({'train_loss' : loss.detach(), 
               'train_accuracy' : self.train_metric.compute()})
```

at the epoch end.